# How to implement a Xamarin Forms SwipeGesture on small screens

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin-forms-4

I have a Xamarin Forms app where I add to a MAIN VIEW 3 views: view 1 / header, view 2, view 3.
On Desktop I want to have them (and I already have them) this way:
[image]

What I'm looking is a different behaviour just for small screens. I would like to "show/hide" view 2 & view 3 with SwipeGesture, and have something like this:

[image]
[image]

Whenever I swipe, I get View 3 individual. If I swipe back, I get View 2. How can I make it through SwipeGesture? Maybe combining with OnIdiom, but how? What if the desktop app they have resized small? That's why I want to have something like breakpoints of the screen instead of OnIdiom.
Is there a way to do it on XAML without code behind?

Comment: What do you mean you want to change the View by swiping do you want them like tabs or view pagers I am not sure

Comment: Changing the view by swipping, no tabs. Or if I have tabs, without showing tab header / title

Comment: You could use `CarouselView` ,check  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/carouselview/

Comment: Is it possible to have both visible on desktop and individually on phone?